# HTaccess how to redirect multiple URLs?

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect multiple URLs to the same page.

I could do it this way:

```
Redirect /index.html http://example.com/newdirectory/
Redirect /index1.html http://example.com/newdirectory/
Redirect /index2.html http://example.com/newdirectory/
Redirect /index3.html http://example.com/newdirectory/
Redirect /index4.html http://example.com/newdirectory/
Redirect /index5.html http://example.com/newdirectory/
```

Is there not a better method for doing this? (more clean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes using `RedirectMatch` you can use regex in pattern:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/(index|index1|index2|index3|index4|index5)\.html$ http://example.com/newdirectory/
```

or even more concise:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/index[1-5]?\.html$ http://example.com/newdirectory/
```